# minimumSpanningTree throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, iterator, nullpointerexception, priority-queue, minimum-spanning-tree

I've stared and stared at this and it's driving me mad.

Somehow `e = pq.poll( );` makes e have a value of null during a test case for a large minimum spanning tree. A tiny minimum spanning tree works.

I am very grateful for all hints on this problem, and how to solve such problems, as i feel i am way above my head here.

Thank you for your help!

**edit:** it seems my priority queue is empty somehow. Can't figure out why that is though 
:/

**edit2:** I've added the DisjSet class here for extra insight

```
public MyMiniGraph<T> generateMinimumSpanningTree()
{
    int edgesAccepted = 0;
      //give all nodes to a class representing disjoint sets
    DisjSet<T> ds = new DisjSet<T>( theGraph.keySet() );

      //set up a new graph to represent the minimum spanning tree
    MyMiniGraph<T> minSpanTree = new MyMiniGraph<T>();
      //initialize minSpanTree with all theGraphs nodes
    Iterator<T> nodeIter = theGraph.keySet().iterator();
    while(nodeIter.hasNext())
        minSpanTree.addNode( nodeIter.next() );

      //order all edges in theGraph in a priority queue
    PriorityQueue<Edge> pq = new PriorityQueue<Edge>(allEdges);
    Edge e;

      // Kruskals algorithm. Accepts the smallest edges in order
      // if they are not part of the same set which would cause a cycle. 
    while(edgesAccepted < currentSize-1)
    {
        e = pq.poll( );

        T uset = ds.find( e.n1 );
        T vset = ds.find( e.n2 );

        if(uset != vset)
        {
            // Accept the edge
            edgesAccepted++;
            ds.union(uset, vset);

             //if the edge is accepted, add it to minSpanTree
            minSpanTree.connectNodes(e.n1, e.n2, e.cost);
        }

    }
    return minSpanTree;
}
```

class declaration and some members:

```
public class MyMiniGraph<T extends Comparable<? super T>> implements MiniGraph<T>
{
      // The Graph containing all the nodes and their edges
    private Map< T, HashSet<Edge> > theGraph = new HashMap< T, HashSet<Edge> >( );
      // Keeps track of theGraphs current size
    private int currentSize = 0;
      // Keeps track of the current Edge quantity
    private int numEdges = 0;
      // TreeSet containing all edges
    private TreeSet<Edge> allEdges = new TreeSet<Edge>();
      // edge representing class with its associated nodes and weight
```

the DisjSet class:

```
import java.util.*;

public class DisjSet<K extends Comparable<? super K>>
{
  //HashMap containing 1. K itself, 2. Ks parent. K no.2 is null if K has no parent 
private HashMap<K,K> sets = new HashMap<K,K>();

public DisjSet(Set<K> s)
{
    if(s.isEmpty())
        throw new IllegalStateException("Empty DisjSet argument");

    Iterator<K> nodes_iter = s.iterator();

    while(nodes_iter.hasNext())
        sets.put( nodes_iter.next(), null );
}
  // recursive method to find o_nodes sets root node
public K find(K o_node)
{
    if(sets.get(o_node) == null)
        return o_node;
    else
        return find( sets.get(o_node) );
}
/**
 * connects set 2 to set 1
 * @param root1     root of set 1 
 * @param root2     root of set 2
 */
public void union( K root1, K root2)
{
    sets.put(root2, root1);
}
}
```

Failure trace if it helps?:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at MyMiniGraph.generateMinimumSpanningTree(MyMiniGraph.java:274)
at MyMiniGraphTest.testGenerateMinimumSpanningTreeLarge(MyMiniGraphTest.java:401)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:76)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:49)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Comment: How are edges compared to one another?  It seems like if your comparison on edges was broken, then you would be getting this behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your test set contain a connected graph? If not, it will fail...

If you add the test I gave in the other answer, you will get an MST of the connected subgraphs - but it's (obviously) impossible to build an MST for the whole graph.

Comment: Yes    `// The Graph containing all the nodes and their edges
    private Map< T, HashSet<Edge> > theGraph = new HashMap< T, HashSet<Edge> >( );
` The Edge objects has references to both connected nodes and a cost

Comment: @Alexander: But are there edges connecting all nodes into one (1) connected graph?

Comment: @Alexander E: Connected = "there is a path from any point to any other point in the graph"

Comment: Aha, well, yes the test case creates a single graph not sub graphs by my understanding

Comment: You could test it by doing a search through the graph (e.g. breadth first), and verify that all nodes are actually visited. If they are not, there's an error with the test set. Otherwise, DisjSet could be the source of your problems :-)

Comment: Did you find out whether the graph is actually connected?

Comment: sorry i haven' replied in a while. I handed this work in unfinished, and school moves so fast so im afraid i have to work on other things. Hopefully ill get back to this soon and finish it.

Answer (score 1):

Try calling `pq.take()` and not `pq.poll()`. Poll will return null on an empty queue, take will block until there is an element available.

Comment: somehow take doesn't seem to exist for me + i noticed the priority queue seems to be empty somehow

Comment: My bad: PriorityQueue http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html doesn't have it, but PriorityBlockingQueue http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/PriorityBlockingQueue.html does. You might want to use that.

Comment: `PriorityBlockingQueue` offers `take()`, but Alexander's implementation is not using threads, so should there be a need for this?

Comment: maybe `while(edgesAccepted < currentSize-1 && pq.size() > 0)
` is a better solution to my problem then? (well not a solution)

Comment: @Alexander: Depending on how you want the algorithm to behave. If you do this test, you need to traverse the graph to see if you actually got an MST. Otherwise, you could have MSTs for several subgraphs. Another option could be to catch the NullpointerException, if the result is not interesting when the graph is not connected.

Comment: @Arve how do i catch a nullpointer exception, and what is a interesting result. Thank you for all the help

Comment: This all depends on what your initial problem is. If you do not want the result if the graph is not connected (ie a connected MST can't be built for the whole graph), then the NullPointerException can be caught [[Tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/)]. It is cleaner to write an if-test at the end of the algorithm instead, as NullPointerExceptions can appear in several places if one does something wrong. "if I did not get all the n-1 edges - I do not have a connected MST". Depending on what the MST is used for in the end, this could still be a valid result.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested your code, but at least PriorityQueue.poll() returns null if the queue is empty.

How about changing:

```
while(edgesAccepted < currentSize-1)
```

to

```
while(edgesAccepted < currentSize-1 && pq.size() > 0)
```

Comment: Yes, that fails the test. seems my priority queue is empty somehow